# Ist die Verwendung des Worts "drakonisch" in Bezug auf Quarantänemaßnahmen angebracht?

Tags: meaning

In den letzten Wochen liest man aus gegebenem Anlass<sup>1</sup> immer wieder von "drakonischen Maßnahmen", wenn es darum geht, ganze Ortschaften vorübergehend unter Quarantäne zu stellen.

Ein paar Beispiele:

> Ebenfalls ins Bild passt, dass die Deutschen drakonische Maßnahmen überproportional häufig ablehnen. Ganze Dörfer oder Städte unter Quarantäne zu stellen (...)

(["Von wegen „German Angst“ – die Deutschen sind in der Corona-Krise ausgesprochen cool", Welt.de](https://www.welt.de/wirtschaft/article206352967/Coronavirus-Bundesbuerger-weniger-besorgt-als-Menschen-in-anderen-Laendern.html))

> Für die meisten Infizierten ist das Virus unbedenklich, aber sie können die Gefahr leicht übertragen. Deshalb sind drakonische Maßnahmen richtig. (...) Messen werden abgesagt, Reiseverbote verhängt, Schulen und Kitas geschlossen, ganze Volkswirtschaften stürzen ab.

(["Berechtigter Aufwand", taz](https://taz.de/Schutz-gegen-das-Coronavirus/!5666035/))

> Um die Epidemie so gut es geht einzugrenzen, werden teilweise drakonische Maßnahmen getroffen: Kreuzfahrtschiffe liegen wochenlang von der Außenwelt isoliert vor Anker, Flugzeugpassagiere werden sofort nach der Landung einquartiert, tausende Reisende stehen weltweit unter Quarantäne.

(["Coronavirus könnte sich über Flughafen Frankfurt in Deutschland ausbreiten", Frankfurter Neue Presse](https://www.fnp.de/frankfurt/coronavirus-deutschland-flughafen-frankfurt-einfallstor-covid-19-13557246.html))

**Ist das Wort "drakonisch" in diesem Zusammenhang korrekt verwendet?**

Ich verstand "drakonisch" bislang durchaus als hart, unerbittlich, in Bezug auf Entscheidungen, die andere Menschen betreffen - jedoch stets mit dem Ziel, sich gegenüber eben jenen Menschen eben "drakonisch" zu verhalten. Sprich: Sind Maßnahmen, Entscheidungen oder Gesetze "drakonisch", so sind sie dies eben genau deswegen, weil sie die Betroffenen gezielt schädigen bzw. bei den potenziell Betroffenen einen entsprechenden Einschüchterungseffekt hervorrufen sollen, damit diese aus Furcht vor (weiteren) Sanktionen ihr Verhalten ändern.

Betrachte ich diverse Quellen, ist dies zwar nirgendwo ausdrücklich klargestellt, jedoch deuten die Beispiele meines Erachtens fast ausnahmslos in diese Richtung:

- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/drakonisch):

  - Als Verwendungsbeispiele, auf die sich "drakonisch" beziehen kann, werden genannt: Strenge, Strafen, Verordnungen, Maßnahmen, Gesetze, Mittel. Zumindest die ersten zwei haben einen klar disziplinarischen Charakter, die anderen enthalten dies zumindest (und sind an der Stelle nicht klarer abgegrenzt).
  - Auch die Wordcloud mit den typischen Verbindungen enthält überwiegend Begriffe, die mit Bestrafung zu tun haben, außerdem ein paar mal Begriffe aus dem Themengebiet des Sparens.
  - Außerdem geht es in allen fünf Beispielen um Bestrafung beziehungsweise Einschüchterung.
- [Uni Leipzig](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=drakonisch):

  - Neun der zehn Beispiele gehen in die Richtung einer (zumindest angedrohten) Bestrafung, nur eines enthält die zuvor genannten Sparmaßnahmen.
  - Die häufigsten vier Kookurrenzen beziehen sich auf Strafen, danach folgt wiederum einmal "sparen", der Rest sind relativ allgemeine Wörter wie "sind" oder "muss".

**Anmerkung zum Thema "Sparen"**

Das einzige Themenfeld, das nicht so recht zu meiner Vermutung passen will, "drakonisch" beinhalte den Aspekt der Verhaltenslenkung durch Strafe/Strafandrohung, ist das Sparen, welches in den meisten Quellen mit wenigen Beispielen zur Verwendung mit "drakonisch" enthalten ist. Mein Verdacht ist jedoch, dass die Verbindung von "drakonisch" mit "Sparmaßnahmen" sich erst in den letzten Jahren im Rahmen der Finanzprobleme diverser EU-Staaten (insbesondere womöglich Griechenland?) entwickelt hat und an sich ebenso aus dem Rahmen fällt wie die Verwendung von "drakonisch" in Bezug auf Maßnahmen zum Gesundheitsschutz.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Da der Kontext für zukünftige Leser spätestens in ein paar Jahren nicht mehr offensichtlich sein dürfte: Dieser Beitrag wurde in den ersten Wochen, in denen sich [SARS-CoV-2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SARS-CoV-2) in Deutschland ausgebreitet hat, verfasst.

Comment: Die Darstellung der Verbindungen bei DWDS als "hat mit Strafen zu tun" ist m.E. stark vom Wunsch gefärbt sich qua Recherche nicht die schöne Frage kaputt zu machen. Einschnitte, Gegenmaßnahme, Maßnahme, Sicherheitsmaßnahme, Vorkehrung, Regiment - das alles sind Begriffe die prächtig auf Quarantänemaßnahmen passen. Damit ist die Frage vaporisiert, erledigt.

Comment: Re: sparen, wär das nicht *dragonisch* wegen Dragi von der Zentralbank, Austerity, usw.?

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist "drakonisch" der perfekte Begriff für die Maßnahmen gegen die Ausbreitung, die beispielsweise in China getroffen wurden. Er umschreibt auch die Möglichkeiten des Zwangs, läßt aber offen wie der empfunden und aufgenommen wird. Auch die Zweckmäßigkeit der Maßnahmen wird damit nicht bewertet, nur daß sie hart, umfassend und einschneidend sind und durchgesetzt werden.

Einerseits *kann* eine Strafe drakonisch sein, aber drakonisch muß *nicht nur* auf Strafen angewendet werden (siehe DWDS link im OP), sondern auch Verordnungen, Maßnahmen, Mittel ...

Man liest in Deutschland würden die in China getroffenen Maßnahmen als "unangemessen" bezeichnet und wohl nicht akzeptieren werden, während sie von der chinesischen Bevölkerung größtenteils klaglos hingenommen wurden. Die Bedeutung von "drakonisch" scheint relativ zu sein und vom Kulturkreis abzuhängen.

Also, meiner Meinung nach: perfekte Wortwahl.

Comment: "Auch die Zweckmäßigkeit der Maßnahmen wird damit nicht bewertet" - wenn man davon spricht, dass jemand "drakonisch bestraft" wird, schwingt dort meiner Meinung nach durchaus die Wertung mit, dass die Strafe *unangemessen* hart ausfällt.

Comment: Ich denke nicht das "drakonisch" zwangsläufig "unangemessen" beinhaltet, aber die Grenze zwischen dien beiden Begriffen und vielleicht "rücksichtslos" kann natürlich fließend sein und vom persönlichen Befinden abhängen, klar. Drakon hat ja auch Willkür und Fehden in der bestehenden Handhabe des Rechts abgeschafft, seinerzeit ...

Comment: Ich finde durch die Beschreibung einer Maßnahme als "drakonisch" liefert die Beschreibung die Behauptung, wie die Maßnahmenempfänger sie empfinden (sollen). Insofern gilt für mich die Aussage "lässt offen wie der empfunden und aufgenommen wird" nur solange der Text auch Reaktionen der Betroffenen vermittelt. In allen anderen Fällen wird die Einschätzung der Redaktion mit der Reaktion der Betroffenen gleichgesetzt - einfach weil diese verschwiegen wird.

Comment: Ich meine auch, dass die Bedeutung des Wortes sowohl "unangemessen hart" umfasst als auch "hart, aber angemessen".

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *drakonisch* basiert auf einem Vergleich: Es geht um Strafen, die den von [Drakon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drakon) vorgesehenen gleichen, welche man als hart ansieht (Todesstrafe bei geringen Vergehen, Schuldknechtschaft). Die Herkunft des Wortes erklärt die beobachtete Kollokation.

Alles Darüberhinausgehende – etwa die Frage, ob die Strafe unangemessen ist oder ob sie der Abschreckung dienen soll – ist meines Erachtens sekundär. Das sind Gedanken, die allgemein mit dem Thema Strafen verbunden sind, aber nicht spezifisch mit als drakonisch bezeichneten Strafen. Bei *harten, strengen, scharfen* Strafen würden sich die gleichen Fragen stellen.

An den Vergleich einer Strafe mit den Strafen Drakons läßt sich ein zweiter Vergleich anschließen: Wenn irgendeine Maßnahme in ihrer Wirkung als einer harten Strafe gleichkommend empfunden wird, kann man sie als *drakonisch* bezeichnen.

Das Absagen einer Messe oder die vorübergehende Schließung von Schulen und Kindergärten als *drakonisch* zu bezeichnen, ist in meinen Augen eine klassische journalistische Hyperbel und als solche zu kritisieren, aber kein Fehler. Wenn es aber darum geht, ganze Ortschaften unter Quarantäne zu stellen, dürfte das in individualistischen (egoistischen?) Gesellschaften wie der unseren tatsächlich als drakonisch, also als harte Strafe, empfunden werden. Dann wäre die Verwendung des Wortes noch nicht einmal eine Übertreibung.

Der Vergleich einer Maßnahme (und das schließt Quarantänemaßnahmen ein, welche dazu dienen, Schaden von Menschen abzuwenden) mit einer Strafe erscheint mir als übliche Metapher: Etwas, das unangenehm wie eine Strafe ist, wird als solche bezeichnet, auch wenn es keine ist. Einige Beispiele für metaphorische Bestrafungen:

> Mit euch ist man gestraft! *(Ausruf des Vaters über die Familie)*
>
> Mitleid vom politischen Gegner – das ist die Höchststrafe in der Politik. ([Südkurier](https://www.suedkurier.de/baden-wuerttemberg/Schlechte-Umfragewerte-ein-angefeindeter-Chef-Die-Suedwest-CDU-steckt-in-der-Falle;art417930,10044413?))
>
> Häftlinge in nordrhein-westfälischen Gefängnissen, die schon mit einer HIV-Infektion oder einer Aids-Erkrankung gestraft sind […] ([law blog](https://www.lawblog.de/index.php/archives/2011/page/38/))

Manchmal werden sogar die Folgen des eigenen Handelns als Strafe angeführt, so daß die gesetzliche Bestrafung überflüssig werden oder zumindest milder ausfallen soll.

> Der Verteidiger der Angeklagten schlug eine Sperre von vier Monaten und eine Geldstrafe von 750 Euro vor. Die Frau sei selbst gestraft genug, da sie von ihrem Ehemann täglich Vorwürfe bekomme. ([Leonberger Kreiszeitung](https://www.leonberger-kreiszeitung.de/inhalt.prozess-in-leonberg-aus-liebe-zum-sohn-betrunken-auto-gefahren.1c7c3bf4-a435-479b-b89e-bc9b70a33892.html))

Zu solchen Verwendungen siehe DWB [Strafe](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=strafe), Bedeutung 9) *noth, plage, pein, ungemach* mit einigen Beispielen sowie DWB [strafen](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=strafen) unter C. 2) d).

> wann ein land mit regenten gestrafet ist, ... ohne die geringste fähigkeit zum dienste der republik
>
> nehmen sie mirs nicht übel, herr pfarrer, womit hab ichs verschuldet, dasz ich mit so einem menschen gestraft bin?

Comment: Ok. Vielleicht kann ich persönlich nur nichts mit der (meines Erachtens vollkommen irrationalen) Sichtweise anfangen, eine Maßnahme zur Krankheitsbekämpfung/-prävention (so paternalistisch, einschränkend und ggf. kritikwürdig sie auch sei) als "Strafe" zu kategorisieren. So lange eine Maßnahme nicht gezielt dazu ergriffen wird, um dem Betroffenen aufgrund eines Verhaltens oder einer Eigenschaft genau die auftretenden Nachteile gezielt zu dessen Schaden zu bereiten, tue ich mich schwer damit, von einer "Strafe" zu sprechen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Aber man kann doch schon die Krankheit allein als Strafe ansehen? Das ist eine ganz normale Metapher. Oder ein Zeitungsbeleg: *Mitleid vom politischen Gegner – das ist die Höchststrafe in der Politik.*

Comment: "Aber man kann doch schon die Krankheit allein als Strafe ansehen?" - von wem soll diese Strafe deiner Meinung nach erlassen worden sein, und als Bestrafung wofür? Ich kenne eigentlich nur die Redewendung "Das ist eine Strafe." in dem Sinn, dass der bemängelte Umstand so unangenehm ist, dass man ihn *gut als Strafe für irgendwas einsetzen könnte*. Das bedeutet freilich nicht, dass man den Umstand im aktuellen Kontext tatsächlich als (von irgendwem erlassene) Strafe ansieht, und dasselbe gilt wohl für deinen Zeitungsbeleg.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das klingt jetzt ein bißchen nach Metaphernphobie. Es gibt einen Vergleich, zwischen den verglichenen Dingen gibt es Gemeinsamkeiten und Unterschiede. Eine Krankheit ist unangenehm wie eine Strafe, aber nicht von Menschen verhängt. Das Bild von der Krankheit als Strafe kommt vielleicht aus dem Buch Hiob, hat sich aber davon gelöst: *Häftlinge […] die schon mit einer HIV-Infektion oder einer Aids-Erkrankung gestraft sind* [lawblog](https://www.lawblog.de/index.php/archives/2011/page/38/). – Der Vater behauptete manchmal, mit mir bzw. der Familie gestraft zu sein.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Inwieweit klärt die Frage, ob man eine Krankheit sei es metaphorisch, sei es als austerbende, religiöse Ansicht, als Strafe bezeichnen kann die Frage, ob man Maßnahmen gegen die Krankheit als solche bezeichnen kann? Überträgt sich das von der Krankheit auf die Maßnahme wie ein (perfekte Analogie, sic!) Virus? :)

Comment: @userunknown Bitte keine Quatschkommentare. Es geht um Metaphern. Die Krankheit als Strafe kann man gerne wieder komplett aus der Diskussion streichen. Die relevante Metapher ist die Quarantäne als Strafe.

Comment: @David: Die Bevölkerung mag ja Maßnahmen wie Strafen empfinden, aber das Verwaltungshandeln ist im Rechtsstaat nie Strafe. Drakonisch wird eben nicht exklusiv für Strafen verwendet sondern bedeutet schlicht rigoros, drastisch, usw. Der Umweg über Empfindungen ist m.E. überflüssig. Dennoch +1.

Comment: @userunknown Sowohl du als auch O. R. Mapper scheinen zu glauben, daß es relevant wäre, ob etwas eine bestimmte Sache **ist**. Aber der Gebrauch von Metaphern impliziert doch keine Geisteskrankheit: *Du bist mein Sonnenschein, ein Zahnrad im Getriebe, ein Schaumschläger* (wenn ich wieder unpassende Beispiele gewählt haben sollte, bitte selber andere ausdenken) heißt doch nicht, daß jemand im Wortsinne für *Sonnenschein, Zahnrad, Schaumschläger* gehalten wird, sondern nur, daß er in einer als relevant empfunden Eigenschaft diesen ähnelt oder gleichgesetzt wird.

Comment: DavidVogt: Ich denke weder @O.R.Mapper , noch ich haben angedeutet, dass drakonische Maßnahmen/Strafen nur von Herrn Drakon persönlich ausgesprochen/angeordnet/verhängt werden können.

Answer (score 0):

Gemessen an der gelierderten Definition des Wortes `drakonisch` - fehlerhafte Verwendung, denn das Ziel der Maßnahmen - wie in der Frage herausgestellt - ist der Schutz der Gesellschaft und die Einschränkung des Einzelnen, als unvermeidbar/Kollateralschaden deklariert, also keine Bestrafung.

Für Einzelne - besonders bei denen, die ohne Infektion sind - kann es sich als Strafe anfühlen: für den Lebenswandel der zur Infektion führte bzw. für den Lebenswandel um (zufällig/unschuldig) am Ort der Infektion zu sein.

Objektiv bleibt:

- dass die Maßnahmen auf den Teil der Bevölkerung angewendet werden soll, der den Kriterien entspricht - und dass es ein Eingriff in die bisher genutzten/bestehenden Rechte darstellt.
- dass das Ziel der Maßnahmen einen Schutz der Bevölkerung darstellen soll: für die Noch-Gesunden und für die Schon-Kranken.
- das die Wahrnehmung vom Kontext auf der Empfangsseite abhängt - der Kurs durch die Wortwahl auf der Sendeseite gesetzt wird (neudeutsch: [Framing](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Framing))

Vor Gericht wird gestritten, welches Recht (und welche Pflicht) im konkreten Fall höher wiegt. Schon die Grundrechte sind sich gegenseitig im Weg.

Publikationen verwenden, was nach ihrem jeweiligen Blickwinkel<sup>1</sup> angemessen ist:

- staatliche Beschneidungen ablehnen: Einschränkungen sind eine Bestrafung
- Aufmerksamkeit erzeugen: drastisch übertreiben
- Sagen was ist: objektiv formulieren
- Sagen was ist: plastisch für den einfachen Hans Meier formulieren
- ...

Bzw.: was auch immer beim Schreiben entsteht.

Bei all dem wird Sprache genutzt und somit geformt und Worte/Redewendungen in ihrer Bedeutung geändert. Daher teile ich die Beobachtung, dass insbesondere staatliche Sparmaßnahmen in der jüngeren Vergangenheit als Bestrafung betrachtet wurden. Was nur funktioniert, falls die Annahme verbreitet ist, dass Sparen = Bestrafung.

D.h., der gesellschaftliche und persönliche Konsens über angebracht/normal/überzogen/verharmlosend/perfide/scheinheilig/... und der eigene Kontext und die eigene Wahrnehmung entscheiden darüber, wie eine Information zur Wortwahl passt.

Einfaches Beispiel:

- "Das Weib hat gesagt, ..." klingt anders als
- "Die Frau hat gesagt, ..." klingt anders als
- "Frau xx hat gesagt, ..." klingt anders als
- "xx hat gesagt, ..."

Die Kontextsetzung variiert schon mit der Bedeutung der Worte [Frau](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Frau) und [Weib](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Weib) über die Zeit. Dazu käme noch üblicher Satzbau und die Auswahl der Verben. Nach meinem Verständnis wäre eine sehr abwertende Formulierung z.B. "Das Weib hat rumgekeift, ...".

---

<sup>1</sup>: Der Blickwinkel setzt sich u.a. zusammen aus: ökonomischen/philosophischen/journalistischen/menschlichen/ethischen/juristischen/arbeitsrechtlichen/fehlenden/(... was auch immer das Leben ausmacht) Grundsätzen, denen gefolgt wird, während die Worte veröffentlicht werden.

Comment: Korrektur: "Als Strafe ... für Sippenhaft" - das ist widersinnig. Bitte selbst umformulieren. Auf welche Definitiion von "drakonisch" beziehst Du Dich, bitte?

Comment: @userunknown: hm, okay, die Sippenhaft ist indirekt drin über "am Ort der Infektion sein".  Danke. Duden-Regel 156 hingegen - werd ich nicht warm mit.

Comment: Und welche Definition? Der gelierderten? Der gelieferten? Die von O.R.Mapper gelieferte? Der hat keine geliefert. Liefer doch bitte selbst eine.